# Midi Control Mapping for AKMusicTrack

Tags: audiokit

Using AudioKit, I am trying to add controller data to a AKMusicTrack which already has some AKMidiNoteData on it, Control data like - like volume, filter resonance, filter cut-off freq, and so on, Im not trying to use the filter effects on this particular instance, but I'm having trouble finding samples of the AKMusicTrack.addController(controller: MIDIByte, value: MIDIByte, position: AKDuration) function. Can anyone point me toward some online samples, or a table with the the control values listed?
For example some manufacturers have pan or envelope attack mapped to midi control 20 or 25 e.t.c